Several derived instances of an abstract base class throwing mypy error
I cannot figure out the correct way to get mypy to not complain about the type hinting when using abstract base classes, specifically a container of several of these (more than 2).
As an example:
mapping_1 = {type(i()).__name__: i() for i in [A, B]}  # Fine.
mapping_2 = {type(i()).__name__: i() for i in [A, B, C]}  # Complains.

The full MWE:
import abc
from typing import Mapping, Type


class I(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self): ...


class A(I):
    def foo(self): ...


class B(I):
    def foo(self): ...


class C(I):
    def foo(self): ...


mapping_1 = {type(i()).__name__: i() for i in [A, B]}  # Fine.
mapping_2 = {type(i()).__name__: i() for i in [A, B, C]}  # Complains.
mapping_3: Mapping[str, I] = {type(i()).__name__: i() for i in [A, B, C]}  # Complains.
mapping_4: Mapping[str, Type[I]] = {type(i()).__name__: i for i in [A, B, C]}  # Complains.
mapping_5: Mapping[str, I] = {type(i()).__name__: i for i in [A, B, C]}  # Complains.

I've seen a few posts about adding Type[I] and similar stuff, but I've not been able to get anything working together to appease mypy (version 1.11.2).
Whether I have a container of instances or objects is not so important, albeit I would prefer a container of objects rather than instances.
Some of the complaints:
$ mypy misc.py 
misc.py:23: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "I" with abstract attribute "foo"  [abstract]
misc.py:24: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "I" with abstract attribute "foo"  [abstract]
misc.py:25: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "I" with abstract attribute "foo"  [abstract]
misc.py:25: error: Only concrete class can be given where "type[I]" is expected  [type-abstract]
misc.py:26: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "I" with abstract attribute "foo"  [abstract]
misc.py:26: error: Value expression in dictionary comprehension has incompatible type "type[I]"; expected type "I"  [misc]
Found 6 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)


What does it complain about in mapping_2?

mapping_5 is clearly wrong, i is the type, not an instance.

Added the complaints, and by the time I reach the final few mappings I am just seeing what complaints mypy lists in an attempt to shed light on the issue.

mapping_2 seems to be a Mypy bug: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15554 (I'm not sure about mapping_3 and mapping_4)

Fair enough, looks like that answers the question...

PyRight doesn't complain about anything, but also disavows any knowledge about the value types. (mapping_1, for example, has inferred type dict[Any, Unknown], which also seems odd. Seems pretty clear that dict[Any, I], if not dict[str, I], is a reasonable inference to make.)

as an aside, can't type(i()).__name__ just be i.__name__?
